# Able to check a disabled checkbox on iOS devices

Tags: html, checkbox, disabled-input

I have an input type="checkbox" that is initially disabled using disabled="disabled" attribute. On iOS devices (like iPad or iPod touch), I am still able to toggle the checkbox even though its grayed out and disabled.

I tried using the disabled property as well as the disabled attribute, but still see the problem behavior with the checkbox.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="myCheck" disabled="disabled">

<input type="checkbox" name="myCheck" disabled>
```

Any thoughts on a fix for this issue on iOS devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into this myself. It's not an issue of iOS, as Jonathon Stark's test page worked perfectly fine. I found it was an issue of a library I'm using: energizejs

I created an issue for it: https://github.com/davidcalhoun/energize.js/issues/15
And also created a jsfiddle to prove the issue (linked on github)

Not sure if you're using that or not, but it's likely some piece of code you have is mucking with it.

Answer (score 1):

Hm... I can't reproduce the issue. What browser/OS/device versions are you testing on?

Comment: Safari on an iPod Touch iOS 6.0.1. I do see the issue on iPad and iPhone emulators too but not on any Android device.

Comment: Hm... can you share a link to the page that has the bug? Also, visit this page on your iPod and try to toggle the disabled checkbox: http://jonathanstark.com/labs/disabled-checkbox-test.html